# Verify integrity of EFI file before chainloading

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

Can I, in GRUB, configure it to verify if the EFI file it is going to chainload being signed (using the Secure Boot database) and refuse to boot if not signed?
I had to disable secure boot for GRUB to allow me to dual-boot between Android and Windows. I don't want to lose that security for my Windows system.
I know GRUB can check the signature of Linux kernels, but what about EFI bootloaders? Is it possible? How?

Comment: you can disable `grub` and just Secure Boot your kernel. that's the far more straightforward way to go. `grub` is just in your way and doesn't make any sense on EFI systems.

Comment: I don't want to disable GRUB, I want to have the choice of the OS at startup. I want to check the integrity of an .efi file, not a linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question resolved itself:

If GRUB attempts to chainload a file that is not accepted by Secure Boot (if Secure Boot is activated), it will get an Access Denied error.